# JSF, Richfaces, AJAX Disable Polling when MouseOver dropdownmenu

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

In my JSF application, I have a a4j:poll, and a richfaces.dropdownmenu.

Is there anyway to disable the polling when the user has his mouse over the dropdownmenu?

the problem I'm facing is that while someone is accessing the dropdownmenu, the poll kicks in and refresh the page, and the user has to go thru the dropdownmenu selection again.

the polling is quite frequent (like every 10seconds) to refresh the content on the page. and the drop down menu has 3-4 level deeps.  That's why its like playing a video game and navigating the dropdownmenu.

Comment: So the poll is also updating the dropdownmenu? Why exactly?

Comment: The poll update the table, and the table is encompassed within a panel with a dropdownmenu on the header (and the header has a counter for the number of rows), so on the poll, it pretty much refresh everything in the page.

Comment: Search stackoverflow for a similar but PrimeFaces related question. Solution might work here to

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion, I end up selectively rerender every single sub component instead of rerender just the panel which also cover the dropdownmenu and it rerender nicely now.